# Repository.RemoveUntrackedFiles() : access denied

Tags: asp.net, git, iis, github, libgit2sharp

```
Windows Server 2008 
McAfee Agent v4.8.0.1938 
no indexing service 
ASP.NET C# app 
libgit2sharp v0.21.0.176 NuGet package
```

My ASP.NET app uses libgit2sharp `Repository.Clone()` method to clone a GitHub repo to local repo

Running my app tests on my local workstation, I perform various operations against this repo with no issues.

However, once my app is deployed to a remote server and hosted inside IIS , I'm encountering what appear to be either permissions or locking issues.

`Repository.RemoveUntrackedFiles()`

Exception thrown :

> Failed to rename lockfile to 'c:/github/my-org/my-repo/.git/index':
>   Access is denied.

If I re-attempt the operation it again fails but this time with a different exception :

> The index is locked. This might be due to a concurrent or crashed
>   process.

Subsequent attempts ( no matter how many ) fail with this same exception.

Issue is not resolved with iisreset or reboot.

If I re-create the local repo by going to cli and deleting local repo folder and then running git clone, I'm now able to successfully execute various git operations until I again attempt `Repository.RemoveUntrackedFiles()` at which point the above error-sequence re-occurs.

EDIT : I'm also encountering similar issues with

Repository.Checkout()

Exception thrown :

> Failed to rename lockfile to 'c:/github/my-org/my-repo/.git/index':
>   Access is denied.

I then go to the server and from the command line attempt git checkout master :

```
c:\github\opentable\service-ot-frontdoor-config>git checkout master
fatal: Unable to create 'c:/github/opentable/service-ot-frontdoor-config/.git/index.lock': File exists.
```

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.

Comment: *"I'm encountering what appear to be either permissions or locking issues."* -> With regard to *"Failed to rename lockfile to"*, are those transient issues or do they happen each and every time you try it. Do they disappear after an iisreset? After a reboot? What version of LibGit2sharp are you using? Is there an anti-virus running on your server? An indexing service?

Comment: I edited original post to include all info you requested

Comment: nulltoken any ideas ?

Comment: Hmmm. That doesn't seem to be a trivial issue. Please log an entry in the **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues)**.

Comment: i filed an issue https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1128 when do you think you could look at this ?

Comment: I think this kind of comment should rather be logged in the issue rather than in this question ;-)